# Sorting long date with jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am new to jQuery etc. but am building a website with HTML tables and have managed to get jQuery tablesorter working. However in one of the columns I have long dates like 5 Jun, 2017.

When sorted by date column, it is sorting the rows like this:

6 Jul, 2017

29 Jun, 2017

21 May, 2018

The code I am using in the head section is:

```
<!-- load jQuery and tablesorter scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,1]]} );
});
</script>
```

And my table looks like this:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped tablesorter">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col class="col-lg-2">
                        <col class="col-lg-2">
                        <col class="col-lg-5">
                        <col class="col-lg-3">
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Event</th>
                            <th>Organiser</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>29 Jun, 2017</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>Book Club</td>
                            <td>John Smith</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6 Jul, 2017</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>Book Club</td>
                            <td>John Smith</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>21 May, 2018</td>
                            <td>Chicago</td>
                            <td>Book Expo</td>
                            <td>Bob Smith</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use shortDate parser and data-date-format option within your th tag for date column. Here is jsfiddle for your code    https://jsfiddle.net/savicmi/htLdapj8/`<th data-sorter="shortDate" data-date-format="d MMM yyyy">Date</th>`.

More about tablesorter date format options on https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-date-format.html.

Comment: Thanks very much! I couldn't get it to work until I changed <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> to <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.14/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script> which is what you appear to be using. The dates are sorting correctly now, but the CSS is no longer working, specifically the gif arrows are no longer appearing next to the column headings. Any ideas?

Comment: The CSS looks like this:

table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(/img/bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(/img/asc.gif);
}

table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(/img/desc.gif);

Comment: Include css file in your html file,
 for example this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.14/css/theme.default.min.css.

Comment: Thanks! That worked but is there a way I can only use part of that CSS? I don't want to change the font sizes etc. I just want to add the arrows.

Comment: Get classes what you want from that css. See updated JSFiddle for arrow classes
https://jsfiddle.net/savicmi/htLdapj8/7/.